# How to sed -e 's///' everything except a specific pattern?

Tags: sed

How can I substitute everything in a string with sed except % and any number directly succeding it? Meaning, everything except strings such as:

`%1`
`%1000`
`%55`
etc.

Given strings of this form:

```
    1: [18x14] [history 1/2000, 268 bytes] %3
    2: [18x14] [history 1/2000, 268 bytes] %4 (active)
```

I only want to get the `%3` and `%4` parts. The numbers can go up to `999`.

Comment: Some sample input and expected output might help.  As of now, the question isn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry for that. Given strings of this form:

`1: [18x14] [history 1/2000, 268 bytes] %3`
and
`2: [18x14] [history 1/2000, 268 bytes] %4 (active)`

I only want to get the `%3` and `%4` parts. The numbers can be up to `999`.

Comment: does each line contain only one  % sign?

Comment: Yes @miracle173, each line does only contain one % sign.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/^.*\(%[0-9]\+\).*$/\1/' input
```

Assuming that a line contains at most one of those `%123` tokens and that every line contains such a token.

The `\( \)` meta character mark a match-group - which is then referenced in the substitution via the `\1` back-reference. `^`/`$` match the beginning/end of a line.

Otherwise you can pre-filter the input, e.g.:

```
$ grep '%[0-9]\+' input | sed 's/^.*\(%[0-9]\+\).*$/\1/'
```

(when not all lines contain such a token)

Another variant:

```
$ sed 's/\(%[0-9]\+\)/\n\1\n/g' | grep '%[0-9]'
```

(when a line may contain multiple of those tokens)

Here are line breaks inserted directly before and after each token - in the first part of the pipe. Then the `grep` part removes all non `%123` token lines.

Comment: + is a gnu extension... without that (on bsd / os x) it would be `sed 's/^.*\(%[0-9]\{1,\}\).*$/\1/' input`

Answer (score 7):

You might be better off using `grep -o` in this case:

```
grep -oP '\B%[0-9]{1,3}\b' inputfile
```

Assuming that your version of `grep` supports Perl compatible regular expressions (`-P`). Otherwise:

```
grep -o '\B%[0-9]\{1,3\}\b' inputfile
```

---

Using GNU `sed`, one could transliterate spaces to newlines and get the desired lines:

```
sed 'y/ /\n/' inputfile | sed '/^%[0-9]\{1,\}/!d'
```

Answer (score 4):

When working with `sed` it's almost always advisable to:

```
/address then/s/earch/replace/
```

There are two reasons for this. The first is that with multiple lines `/addressing/` is faster - it's optimized only to *find* a match and doesn't bother selecting only portions of a line for editing and so it can narrow the results sooner.

The second reason is that you can play multiple edit operations off of the same address - it makes things much easier.

Of course, in this case, given only the data you show, it makes no practical difference. Still, this is how I would do the thing you ask about:

```
sed '/^[^%]*\|[^0-9]*$/s///g' <<\DATA
    1: [18x14] [history 1/2000, 268 bytes] %3
    2: [18x14] [history 1/2000, 268 bytes] %4 (active)
DATA

#OUTPUT
%3
%4
```

It just selects all characters that are *non-%* characters from the beginning of the line and all *non-numeric* characters from the end of the line in the address and then removes them with `s///` - and that that's that.

In it's current form it might mangle data in unexpected ways if you feed it lines *not* containing a `%digit` combo - and that's why addressing is important. If we alter it a little:

```
/%[0-9]/s/[^%]*\|[^0-9]*$//g
```

It gets safer *and* faster.

Answer (score 2):

My solution doesn't use sed but grep with extended-regex and only-matching options.

```
$ cat file
1: [18x14] [history 1/2000, 268 bytes] %3
2: [18x14] [history 1/2000, 268 bytes] %4 (active)
$ cat file | grep -Eo '%[0-9]+'
%3
%4
```

Using grep in this case is simpler than using sed.

Comment: I would tend to agree about the simpler part - and that it is also faster, but... why do you need `E`? Or `cat`? If you want to ensure at least one numeric match the `+` is not necessary: `grep -o '%[0-9][0-9]*'`- and of course `grep's` primary purpose is to read files - that's why it works on `|pipe` files - so `grep -${opts} ${files}` is all you need, I think.

Comment: I reuse `cat` from the previous command line. I use `E` option and `+` for regexp. `%x` can go up to `%999` in the question. `grep -o '%[0-9]\+' file` and `grep -oE '%[0-9]+' file` are equivalent for numbers over 100.